# Получить полный путь до appdata

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, nasm

Мне нужно узнать путь к папке %appdata%, и записать этот путь в регистр, и использовать данный регистр в коде.

Примерный мой код (использую winapi):

```
global start

extern SHGetSpecialFolderPathA ; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderpatha

section .data
    CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA equ 001ch

section .text
    start:
        push 0
        push CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA
        push 0
        push 0
        call [SHGetSpecialFolderPathA]
```

Comment: Для получения этого пути следует использовать `SHGetKnownFolderPath`

Comment: @user7860670, я возможно не знаю какой-то специфики, но почему именно "следует"? SHGetSpecialFolderPath тоже позволяет получить путь к %appdata%

Comment: @insolor В документации она отмечена как неподдерживаемая, и вместо нее советуют  SHGetFolderPath, которая, в свою очередь, обертка для SHGetKnownFolderPath. Ну и функции с суффиксом `A` по не поддерживают юникод.

Comment: @user7860670, ок, дополнил ответ. По поводу поддержки юникода - я думаю так пока оставить. Если автору вопроса понадобится юникод, тогда придется весь код править, вряд ли это ограничится только одной функцией)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое что нужно сделать - посмотреть документацию: [SHGetSpecialFolderPathA function (shlobj_core.h)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderpatha). В документации написано, что в параметре `pszPath` нужно передать указатель  на буфер (адрес буфера) размером минимум `MAX_PATH` символов, куда будет записан путь:

> pszPath
>
> Type: LPTSTR
>
> A pointer to a null-terminated string that receives the drive and path
> of the specified folder. This buffer must be at least MAX_PATH
> characters in size.

```
global start

extern SHGetSpecialFolderPathA ; https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderpatha

section .data
    CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA equ 001ch
    MAX_PATH equ 260
    buffer times MAX_PATH db 0

section .text
    start:
        push 0
        push CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA
        push buffer
        push 0
        call [SHGetSpecialFolderPathA]
        ; После выполнения в буфере buffer будет путь
```

Результат в отладчике:

[image: Скриншот]

---

Также в документации функция `SHGetSpecialFolderPathA` помечена как неподдерживаемая, вместо нее нужно использовать [`SHGetFolderPathA`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) (которая тоже deprecated, вместо нее нужно использовать [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), но мне не удалось получить рабочий результат с помощью этой функции (aka. "ниасилил"), поэтому ниже пример с `SHGetFolderPathA`):

```
global start

extern SHGetFolderPathA

section .data
    CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA equ 001ch
    MAX_PATH equ 260
    buffer times MAX_PATH db 0

section .text
    start:
        push buffer
        push 0
        push 0
        push CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA
        push 0
        call [SHGetFolderPathA]
        ; После выполнения в буфере buffer будет путь
```